# web view in cocso2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

how can I use web view in cocso2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
webView = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,580,400) 
                               frameName:@"mainFrame" 
                               groupName:nil];
[webView setAcceptsTouchEvents:YES];

[view addSubview:webView];

[[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView addSubview:view];

NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them with an extra four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting. Also, [code without explanation](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) isn't terribly useful.